# JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallIntMethodV called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am doing application in android studio using opencv. Code below

```
java.util.List<Mat> result = new java.util.ArrayList<Mat>(2);
List<java.lang.String> outBlobNames = new java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>();
outBlobNames.add(0, "yolo_16");
outBlobNames.add(1, "yolo_23");
tinyYolo.forward(result, outBlobNames);
```

I'm getting an error in this line

```
tinyYolo.forward(result, outBlobNames);
```

Error

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallIntMethodV called with pending exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Ljava/util/ArrayList;.get((I)Ljava/lang/Object;"
```

Comment: Ages ago I played with JNI too, I remember it was useful to enable extra debug information using (one or both of these Java options, did you enable them?) -Xcheck:jni  -verbose:jni  Good luck

Comment: I fixed the problem by changing the opencv version