# problem when running yolo3 on android studio on my phone

Tags: android-studio, android, android-studio-4.0, opencv

I have installed opencv on android studio, and run a canny edge detection successfully on my phone (redmi note 8 pro). but when i want to run yolo3 for object detection using this [link](https://github.com/ivangrov/Android-Deep-Learning-with-OpenCV/tree/master/%5Bpart%205-6%5D%20DNN%20Module%20and%20Tiny%20YOLO), when i push the button to perform object detection, the app is closed, and show a long error which here is its beggining:

[image]

here's app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.m_series_v2_cv_nn"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation project(path: ':openCVLibrary343')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

any help is appreciated. let me know if any more information is required.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60968715/jni-detected-error-in-application-jni-callintmethodv-called-with-pending-except

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the opencv version from 3.4.3 to 3.4.5, and it is working well